# Android: Dialog force closes on create

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Goal is to make a dialog that appears on menu_key pressed, but it keeps force closing. I consulted the official [FAQ on Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), but no luck. Everything was done as explained there, but it still fails as soon as the button is pressed. Here is the creation of the dialog:

```
static final int Choice_ID = 0;

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch(id) {
        case Choice_ID:
            // do the work to define the pause Dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("TEST DIALOG")
                   .setCancelable(true);

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            break;

        //default:
            //dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }
```

And the part about showing looks like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            showDialog(Choice_ID);

        };
};
```

Comment: Please post the logcat errors.

Comment: Everything works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not cause a force close, but you can see the menu if you try setting the value of `dialog`:

```
dialog = builder.create();
```

As in:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Dialog dialog = null;
    switch(id) {
    case Choice_ID:
        // do the work to define the pause Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("TEST DIALOG")
               .setCancelable(true);

        dialog = builder.create();
        break;

    //default:
        //dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: No luck. It suggests me rename `dialog` to `dialog1`. Duplicate local variable. I changed unused `alert` into dialog? Or what part should I change?

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! Will accept your answer as soon as it lets me do so. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help and thanks for accepting my answer. As a note always cut & paste any logcat errors, they help immensely.